# My download speed is throttled to 90Mbps both on WiFi and LAN

Tags: ethernet, windows-11, network-adapter, speed

I have a 400Mbps connection, yet my computer only achieves around 90Mbps on various online speed measuring sites.

While this could be attributed to the fact, that the house itself were connected to only lesser than 400mbps connection, this seems doubtful as my phone measures 140mbps on the same site. I tried the benchmarks both with a cable and a wireless connection.  On the other hand, I achieve an upload speed of also roughly 90Mbps. In my experience, the ratio of upload to download speed is usually a factor of 4-5, so this checks out with a 400Mbps connection.

My mainboard is an [AsRock X670E Pro RS](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X670E%20Pro%20RS/index.asp#Specification)

I installed their Realtek LAN driver.

I also ran

> netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

and restarted. I changed the `Large Send Offload` to disabled and set the `Jumbo Frame` to 16128. Then restarted. I'm still limited at ~90Mbps.

The adapter's properties listed under the device manager are as follows:

```
advanced EEE: disabled
ARP Offload: enabled
EEE Max Support Speed: 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex
Energy-Efficient Ethernet: disabled
Flow Control: Rx & Tx enabled
Gigabit Lite: enabled
Green Ethernet: enabled
Interrupt Moderation: enabled
IPv4 Checksum Offload: Rx & Tx enabled
Jumbo Frame: 16128 Bytes
Large Send Offload v2 (IPv4): disabled
Large Send Offload v2 (IPv6): disabled
Maximum Number of RSS Queue: 2 Queues
Network Address: not present
NS Offload: enabled
Power Saving Mode: enabled
Priority & VLAN: Priority & VLAN enabled
Receive Buffers: 512
Receive Side Scaling: enabled
Shutdown Wake-On-Lan: enabled
Speed & Duplex: Auto Negotiation
TCP Checksum Offload (IPv4): Rx & Tx enabled
TCP Checksum Offload (IPv6): Rx & Tx enabled
Transmit Buffers: 512
UDP Checksum Offload (IPv4): Rx & Tx enabled
UDP Checksum Offload (IPv6): Rx & Tx enabled
VLAN ID: 0
Wake on Magic Packet: enabled
Wake on magic packet when syst: disabled
Wake on pattern match: enabled
WOL & Shutdown Link Speed: 10Mbps First
```

The router is [Huawei WA8021V5](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100136342)

Comment: Don't use jumbo frames unless you can control the MTU on all nodes… which you can't.

Comment: @Tetsujin so at what value should I put it? Options are 4k, 9k 16k or disabled

Comment: Disable. Set MTU to 1400 to play safe just for now. [There are ways to test it for optimal frame size, default is 1500, but depending on what you're passing through 1492 or lower might be optimal. You can find online testers for this.] Check your ethernet is *actually* connecting at gigabit, 90mb/s sounds suspiciously like something is only running 100Base-T.

Comment: Also, there appear to be some false assumptions  including a rrlationship between upload and download speed.  Sorry, but Realtek chipsets are crap and it would not surprise me if that were a major contributor.

Comment: @Tetsujin now that you mention it, under Network&internet > Ethernet it actually says "Link speed (Receive/Transmit): 100/100 (Mbps)".

Comment: That's your problem then ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin how do I change that?

Comment: what happens if you set "Gigabit Lite" setting to disabled?

Comment: @Yorik nothing.